# Falco Installation failure due to GPG key

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, falco

I am trying to install Falco on OCI instance but it is failing with the following error:

Following this blog: https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/post/monitor-oke-cluster-using-falco?source=:so:ch:or:awr::::Cloud&SC=:so:ch:or:awr::::Cloud&pcode=

```
GPG key at https://falco.org/repo/falcosecurity-packages.asc (0x14CB7A8D) is already installed
The GPG keys listed for the "falcosecurity-rpm" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.. Failing package is: falco-0.33.1-1.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: https://falco.org/repo/falcosecurity-packages.asc
```

Any suggestions on how this can be resolved? I am using the latest GPG key.

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest key? [_"On January 18th, 2023 the GPG key used to sign Falco packages has been rotated. Check out the related blog post and make sure you're using the most up-to-date key available at falco.org/repo/falcosecurity-packages.asc, and that you read the section below about package signing."_](https://falco.org/docs/getting-started/installation/)?

Comment: I am using  --> 2026-01-17 Signing Falco Packages Trusted falcosecurity-14CB7A8D.asc
zthe error also shows the same

Comment: Why not install the latest version ([`falco-0.34.0-x86_64.rpm`](https://download.falco.org/?prefix=packages/rpm/)).  Hopefully it is signed by the latest key.